# Fragments not being garbage collected in Android

Tags: android, garbage-collection, fragment

I'm working on an Android app and I'm experiencing frequent out of memory crashes. I fired up DDMS, and it turns out that none of my fragments are ever being garbage collected! I'm releasing all the class variables in onDestroy(), setting all the event listeners to null, and yet still everything just hangs around. When I look at the nearest dominators of the objects, it's often the ROOT that's the dominator. What can I do to get these fragments to be garbage collected?

I'd post code, but this is a very large program and I'm not sure what, if anything, would be more relevant than just describing the problem. I'd really appreciate any insights.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The FragmentManager seems to keep every Fragment forever. Make sure you destroy Fragments when you're done with them, simply detaching doesn't remove them from the manager.

Comment: how do you destory them?